# From Maxwell equations to wave equation: what is the meaning of the differentiation?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, differentiation, maxwell-equations

Starting from the Maxwell's equation in empty space and without charges and currents, we can write the two following equations:

$\bar \nabla \times \bar E= -{{\partial \bar B}\over{\partial t}}$

$\bar \nabla \times \bar B= {{{1} \over {c^2}} \cdot{  {\partial \bar E}\over{\partial t}}}$

Now choosing one particular direction for one of the two fields and **differentiating** the first equation by the time and the second equation by the space (or vice versa) we obtain the wave equation.

**Why we do that?**
What's the physical and theoretical meaning of deriving one equation by the time and the second one by the space? I never understood that. The meaning. Not the math.

Comment: Why would it have any meaning? It's a mathematical operation used to connect the two equations, as in the form as you wrote them, you can't solve for any variable.

Comment: I don't think it has any meaning, it's just a way to solve a PDE. I've solved a lot of coupled ODE systems that the easiest way to uncouple them is to apply an operation (like a derivative) to one of them and substitute the other, this is precisely what is happening here.

Comment: All the physical meaning is in Maxwell's equations. The derivatives just manipulate the equations, without changing their meaning, so they can be combined into a single wave equation. The wave equation exposes additional meaning that was already hidden in the original equations.

Comment: Actually what you are doing is taking the curl of each equation. These are coupled partial differential equations. It turns out taking the curl of both equations introduces the laplacian and it turns out the right-hand sides look like the time-derivatives of the left-hand-side of the equations you started with. So, you can substitute and see that they uncouple. If you view this relativistically in terms of the field tensor, it may look more obvious.